# How do you prove the following integral result

Tags: definite-integrals

How do you prove the result?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x(1-x^2)}dx  = \pi $$

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114086/using-residue-theory-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-sin-pi-xx1-x2

Comment: Indeed it does provide a prove but uses residue theorem. I was interested in a more classical approach. I got as far as splitting into partial fractions but the resulting integrals (all of similar form) are difficult themselves.

Comment: Apologies, perhaps I should have stated 'by elementary' methods.

Comment: @Callie12 By partial fractions, you may get $I = 2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin \pi x}{x} \mathrm{d}x$, right?